# Link to specific tab Bootstrap Codeigniter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, hash, tabs

I'm using codeigniter and I'm having the same problem of the topic:

[Link to specific tab Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352181/link-to-specific-tab-bootstrap/30009100#30009100)

I'm trying as follows but to no sucess:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="<?php echo ($acao == 'listar') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
        <a href="#mytab1" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>&nbsp;Name Link My tab 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($acao == 'cadastro') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
        <a href="#mytab2" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>&nbsp;Name Link My tab 2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($acao == 'tipos') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
        <a href="#mytab2" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>&nbsp;Name Link My tab 3
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the footer:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          // Javascript to enable link to tab
          var hash = document.location.hash;
          if (hash) {
            console.log(hash);
            $('.nav-stacked a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
          }

          // Change hash for page-reload
          $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
            window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
          });
        });
    </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery-ui.js'); ?>"></script>
```

also I tried changing the class in line for:

```
 $('.nav-pills a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
```

and put in the head javascript, but it did not work, where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
$('.nav-stacked a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');

Try

$('.nav-stacked a[href='+hash+']').show();